# Need help with Limit (DirectedInfinity)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I tried to compute the following limit:

```
Limit[Series[
  1/(1/x^2) (Sin[y x]/(x^4))^2 - Sin[y x]/y(x^3) + 1/x^2, {x, 0, 5}], 
 x -> 0, Assumptions -> {y > 0}]
```

the output :

```
DirectedInfinity[Sign[y]^2]
```

What does this means? Is there a solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at what `Series` gives you without the limit.  You will see why.

Comment: @BillWatts Ok. But why when I put like `Limit[y^2/x^4 + (1 - y^4/3)/x^2 + (2 y^6)/45 - (y^8 x^2)/
  315 + (-1 + (2 y^10)/14175) x^4, x -> 0, Assumptions -> {y > 0}]` I got `\[Infinity]`?

Comment: The `O[x^6] on the end of your `Series` seems to be the problem.  Use `Normal` with your `Series` and you get infinity.

Comment: Take another step `FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> y > 0]` which results in `Infinity`.